# Get certain part of string

Tags: vb.net, substring

so im getting from a client, a computer name and an ip. im getting those to my server which picks them up in a textbox with multiline. so, im getting a message like this: Name: xxx-PC; IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ! i want to take the name and the ip to another form, but how do i extract the name/ip when the lenght could always be different?
Thanks

Comment: This is not how StackOverflow works. You start by writing some code, and if you have specific problems/errors, then you post your code and explain your specific problem, and ask a specific question. Then someone might answer. Otherwise, people are not here to code the whole thing for you.

Comment: You find the common char/pattern and go from there. Look into `string manipulation`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with using [Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx)...

Assuming you have **exactly** one set of paired values separated by semi-colon, and each pair has **exactly** one colon separating the name from the value:

```
Dim stringFromServer As String = "Name: xxx-PC; IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
Dim values() As String = stringFromServer.Split(";")
Dim name As String = values(0).Split(":").Last.Trim
Dim IP As String = values(1).Split(":").Last.Trim
Debug.Print("name = " & name)
Debug.Print("IP = " & IP)
```

If your input is more complex then please update with more details.

**---------- Edit ----------**

> I dont really know what i should do to get the string im getting in
>   the textbox

Okay, I read this as:

- You're already successfully connecting with some ~thing~.
- You have already received some data.
- You have already converted that data to a string.

If so, just put it in your TextBox, then use code like I showed you to extract the pieces of data and place them in other TextBoxes:

```
txtChat.Text = yourDataFromSomeWhereElse
Dim values() As String = yourDataFromSomeWhereElse.Split(";")
Dim name As String = values(0).Split(":").Last.Trim
Dim IP As String = values(1).Split(":").Last.Trim
TextBox2.Text = name
TextBox3.Text = IP
```

That's about as much help as I can give you with the information you've provided so far...

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer
its not working for some reason.
so iam getting the info(name/IP) and it sends it to the textbox on the server, i tried:
`If txtChat.Text.Length >= 1 Then
            Debug.Print(TextBox2.Text)
            Debug.Print(TextBox3.Text)
        End If`

this is not quite working, it says when the form is loading:
textbox2.text = xxx-PC
textbox3.text = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

I dont know how the text could be updated any suggestions?

Comment: Each time you get a new response you'll need to use the above code to extract the values and update the appropriate textboxes with those values...

Comment: i just realised, that thats not the problem, the beginning of all that is the stringfrom server, and that string isnt actually from the server, its just definded as: "Name: xxx-PC; IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx". I dont really know what i should do to get the string im getting in the textbox. if i try: Dim stringFromServer As String = txtChat.text (which is the txtbox the content is recieved on) is gives me an error because it cant split something that isnt there.. i really dont know what to do :(

Answer (score 1):

This is a good candidate for Regex.Match() using the pattern

```
"^Name: (.*?); IP: (.*?)$"
```

Breakdown:

- `^` - Beginning of the string
- `Name:` - literal string
- `(.*?)` - Zero or more characters stored in capture group 1
- `; IP:` - literal string
- `(.*?)` - Zero or more characters stored in capture group 2
- `$` - End of the string

Code Sample:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim data As String = "Name: xxx-PC; IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
        Dim name As String = String.Empty
        Dim ip As String = String.Empty

        Dim match = Regex.Match(data, "^Name: (.*?); IP: (.*?)$")
        If match.Success Then
            name = match.Groups(1).Value
            ip = match.Groups(2).Value
        End If

        Console.WriteLine(name)
        Console.WriteLine(ip)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Results:

```
xxx-PC
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kZtyM8)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way (with out using RegEx which is an overkill in this situation, or split at ";" or meany other options...) is to look for the index of the first ":" and the first index of ";", than take a substring form the index of ":" with a length up to the ";".
For the IP it is similar...